# How garbage collector works with Xmx and Xms values

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I have some doubts how the JVM garbage collector would work with different values of Xmx and Xms and machine memory size:
How would garbage collector would work in following scenarios:

```
1. Machine memory size = 7.5GB
   Xmx = 1024Mb
   Number of processes = 16
   Xms = 512Mb
```

I know 16*512Mb already exceeds the machine memory size. How would the garbage collector would work in this scenario. I think the memory usage would be entire 7.5GB in this case. Will the processes would be able to do anything in this? Or they all will be stuck?

```
2. Machine memory size = 7.5GB
   Xmx = 320MB
   Xms is not defined.
   Number of Processes = 16
```

In this, 16*320Mb should be less than 7.5GB. But in my case, memory usage is again reaching 7.5GB. Is it possible? Or I have probably have a memory leak in my application?

So, basically I want to understand when does garbage collector runs? Does it run whenever memory used by the application reached exactly Xmx value? Or they are not related at all?

Comment: The garbage collector does not need to do anything about you using more than your physical memory. Implementing virtual memory is the duty of the operating system. Besides that, there is more than heap memory. There is program code, class meta data, there are stacks, I/O buffers, on so on. So the memory consumption may be higher than your maximum heap size.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things to understand here and then consider in your situation.

Each JVM process has its own virtual address space, which is protected from other processes by the operating system.  The OS maps physical ranges of addresses (called pages) to the virtual address space of each process.  When more physical pages are required than are available, pages that have not been used for a while will be written to disk (called paging) and can then be reused.  When the data of these saved pages is required again they are read back to the same or different physical page.  By doing this you can easily run 16 or more JVMs all with a heap of 1Gb on a machine with 8Gb of physical memory.  The problem is that the more paging to disk that is required the more you are going to degrade the performance of your applications since disk IO is orders of magnitude slower than RAM access.  This is also the reason that the heap space of a single JVM should not be bigger than physical memory.

The reason for having -Xms and -Xmx options is so you can specify the initial and maximum size of the heap.  As your application runs and requires more heap space the JVM is able to increase the heap size within these bounds.  A lot of time these values are set to be the same to eliminate the overhead of having to resize the heap while the application is running.  Most operating systems only allocate physical pages when they're required so in your situation making -Xms small won't change the amount of paging that occurs.

The key point here is it's the virtual memory system of the operating system that makes it possible to appear to be using more memory than you physically have in your machine.